# F test to compare regression coefficients across different groups, using R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, model-comparison

Imagine the following type of dataset: I have a dependent variable Y, two independent variables X and Z, and a variable that can separate the dataset in two smaller datasets.

[image]

I estimated 2 identical OLS regressions for each group separately:

`Alldata_A<-subset(Alldata, group=="A")`

`Alldata_B<-subset(Alldata, group=="B")`

`OLS_A <- lm(Y~Z+X,Alldata_A)`

`OLS_B <- lm(Y~Z+X,Alldata_B)`

Now I am looking for a way to compare both models and to test whether the coefficients significantly differ for the two groups.

This shouldn't be difficult with an F-test, but I do not manage to get a result using R language.

I would be very grateful if someone can suggest which R-function to use for this!

Comment: You say that you "do not manage to get a result using R language." What function have you been using? The easiest way to compare two regression function in R (with the $F$ test) is with the `anova()` function.

Comment: I tried anova(), but if I am correct, anova() works only for different regressions, done on the same sample. I have only one regression, which I estimate on different samples. In addition, anova doesn't work if the sample sizes are not identical (which is my case).

Comment: Another possibility I tried is calculating the confidence intervals for the different parameters, to see if the confidence intervals of the 2 regressions overlap. But this is not yet a real 'test' to see whether the difference are significant, right?

Comment: That could work, but it might be inefficient. Why don't you just interact the group variable with the coefficient you're looking at? `lm(y ~ X:Group + Z:Group)`

Comment: @gmacfarlane Yes, I saw that suggestion in a related question. But it is not applicable to my research because my regression only contains exogenous variables. And group is in my case an endogenous variable. So dummies or interaction terms with group are not allowed. A possiblity I am currently looking at is using the two-sample Z-test to compare the two regressions.